# Isses: Setting size of images

Tags: html

I'm trying to set the size of images in the CSS file.
I set class for both images and try to change size in CSS.
But it's not letting me change size.

Code:

```css
.social-icon{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.instagram .facebook{
  width:8%;
  length:8%;
  margin:5px 10px;
  min-width:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icon">
 <a href="#"><img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/instagram-png-instagram-png-logo-1455.png" alt="insta" class="instagram"/></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124010.png" alt="faceook" class="facebook" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Haruki! Please consider describing what you wanted to achieve with your code so that people having a similar problem can find your question in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no CSS property called `length`, setting `width` and `max-width` is sufficient in this case to make the pictures smaller.

The main issue is that you were missing a comma between your two classes `.facebook` and `.instagram`, so effectively the browser is looking for `.facebook` element inside of `.instagram`.

```css
.social-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.instagram, .facebook {
  width:8%;
  margin:5px 10px;
  min-width:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icon">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/instagram-png-instagram-png-logo-1455.png" alt="insta" class="instagram"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124010.png" alt="faceook" class="facebook" /></a>
</div>
```